# Sorting a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to sort some nodes in c++ that I've stored in a vector.

```
 bool compare_func(const node* a, const node* b)
 {
    return a->getPoint()<b->getPoint();
 }
```

where getPoint() returns a float by which I want to sort my vector.

However, when I run it with:

```
 std::sort(dataSet.begin(), dataSet.end(), compare_func);
```

I get:

```
error C2662: 'node::getStartPoint' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node' to 'node &
error C2662: 'node::getStartPoint' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node' to 'node &'
error C2039: 'sort' : is not a member of 'std'
error C3861: 'sort': identifier not found
```

I have this at the top of my file:

```
using namespace std;
std::vector<node*> dataSet;
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I overloaded the getPoint function and indeed forgot the algorithm include, [I had thought I had included it at one point].

Thanks!

Comment: Is `getPoint` and any other function it uses `const`-qualified ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't refer to `getStartPoint`, so it's either wrong or incomplete. Whatever method you want to call does need to be const-qualified though.

Answer (score 4):

The first two errors look like you're calling `getStartPoint()` on a `const` object, and the member function isn't `const`. To fix that:

```
point getStartPoint() const;
                      ^^^^^
```

The second two are because you haven't included the header that declares `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to provide a `const` overload of `node::getPoint()`:

```
struct node
{
  ...
  SomePoint getPoint() const { return .... ; }
  //                   ^^^^^
};
```

Besides that, you need to include the `<algorithm>` header for `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

and declare your function as const

```
point getStartPoint() const;
```

because you are calling it on `const node`, only functions declared const might be called on const object. Such a function cannot change any class members (except declared as `mutable`).

Declaring a member method results in a function declaration that takes a member pointer as a first parameter.
For example:

```
class node{
public:
    point getStartPoint();
    point getStartPoint(int arg);
};
```

results in

```
point node::getStartPoint(node* this);
point node::getStartPoint(node* this, int arg);
```

but:

```
class node{
public:
    point getStartPoint() const;
    point getStartPoint(int arg) const;
};
```

results in

```
point node::getStartPoint(const node* this);
point node::getStartPoint(const node* this, int arg);
```

thus the error

> error C2662: 'node::getStartPoint' : cannot convert 'this' pointer
>   from 'const node' to 'node &